# Help with translation - Sei Seele, aber säusele nicht!

Tags: german-to-english, joke

Anyone got any good ideas for how this can be successfully translated into English (preserving the "pun")? Context being this comes from a list of amusing things that a witty person said...

> Zu einem Pianisten, der allzusehr im Pianissimo schwelgte, sagte er gelegentlich: “Sei Seele, aber säusele nicht!”

Comment: Your question is about how to express something in English, hence it's off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

I think, this is a pun which works with Saxon dialect. In Saxon dialect, "Sei Seele" und "säusele" could be pronounced nearly the same way.

Literally, the sentence translates to

> Be a soul, but don't whisper.

What is meant, is that the player should "have soul", i.e. play in an expressive and sensitive way. The phrasing to "be soul" does not make too much sense, and I guess, this is only used for the pun mentioned above.

The whole sentence translates as

> Every now and so often he would say to a piano player who would regale on the *pianissimo* a little too much: Play with soul, but don't whisper.

Comment: Thanks - I had actually managed to understand it (but helpful to have confirmed) - but struggling to find a way to translate into English that preserves the humour. Have edited for clarity.

May just have to explain it.

Comment: @ajor I think, there is no way to preserve the pun in translation. :)

Comment: I think "to rustle" instead of "to whisper" brings better across the meaning of "säuseln" here. Also, "piano" (p) and "pianissimo" (pp) are to different volumes.

Comment: @bakunin THanks for the hint with the pianissimo, I corrected the slip of the pen. Not sure about rustle, though.

Comment: I actually didn't get that there was a pun until you brought up Saxon dialect. So the pun might not even work in Hochdeutsch.

Comment: @Arno In standard german, the pun wouldn't work, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at translation, a bit different from that of @JonathanScholbach, though not much so:

> Zu einem Pianisten, der allzusehr im Pianissimo schwelgte, sagte er gelegentlich: “Sei Seele, aber säusele nicht!”

*To a piano player who wallowed all too much in* pianissimo *he said occasionally: "Be a soul, but don't rustle!"*

Answer (score 0):

Approach of convergence:

Word by Word:

> Play with soul, but don't rustle.

Pun: something iconic

> Play like ace, without ace of spades.

German accent and word form [Brain-Looping]:

> Sei [Seele], aber säu(=little pig][se(e)le] nicht.
> Sei säu. Be a little pig.

Answer (score 0):

A better translation (for the assonance/soundplay) is probably "Play soulfully, but not silently", although 'soulfully' in American English tends to imply bombast, not reticence. (Maybe that's the difference btw American and German souls.)

There's also the problem of schwelgen, which to me implies a kind of self-indulgence not necessarily associated with silence or whispering. There might be a pun on sighingly/silently, but it sounds pretty forced.